# Does setting "slave-read-only no" will make slave confirm every hash lookup with the master?

Tags: redis

I want to configure slave to enable writes (`slave-read-only no`). The use case is to enable ephemeral cache.

However, this paragraph in the documentation made me concerned:

> Normally slave nodes will redirect clients to the authoritative master for the hash slot involved in a given command, however clients can use slaves in order to scale reads using the READONLY command.

– http://redis.io/commands/readonly

Does setting `slave-read-only no` will make slave confirm every hash lookup with the master?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "confirm every hash lookup with the master" ? setting ```slave-read-only no``` will just allow write on slave, and the change can't synchronized to other nodes.

Comment: "normally slave nodes will redirect clients to the authoritative master for the hash slot involved in a given command", this. This makes it sound that adding `slave-read-only no` will make the slaves query the master for each command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take note that `slave-read-only` config refers to replication and `READONLY` refers to the redis-cluster command.

If you are not using redis-cluster, you can safely ignore the `READONLY` command documentation. Refer to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf instead. Writes should not replicate nor require lookups to the master. My wireshark dumps on redis with `slave-read-only no` shows no indication of any communication with master as a consequence of writes to the slave itself.

If you are using redis-cluster on the other hand, and referring to the `READWRITE` behavior: Cluster nodes' communication with each other for hash slot updates and other cluster specific messages are optimized to use minimal bandwidth and the least processing time. Communicating hash slot updates most likely do not happen for every write on the slave.