# Read directly from a replica inside Redis cluster

Tags: redis, replication, partitioning, redis-cluster

I want to read directly from a replica inside a Redis cluster but I am getting redirected even if the key actually exist inside the Redis node.

[image: redis cluster replica read]

Checked [READONLY command](https://redis.io/commands/readonly) docs. However, [that is seemed to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642858/463785) in case of Redis Cluster.

How should I configure the Redis cluster so that I can directly read from a replica node for the reads issue against its hash slots? I am OK to read stale data in this case.

Comment: You need to issue the `READONLY` command in same connection to the replica, before the get request. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ItamarHaber oh, nice! that actually worked, thanks a lot! Please put it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`READONLY` command](https://redis.io/commands/readonly) (as well as the [`READWRITE` command](https://redis.io/commands/readwrite) that counteracts it) are applicable per connection in a clustered environment.

While `READWRITE` is the default behavior, in order to change that you'll need to call `READONLY` in the context of the connection that you're using.